# Ubuntu Server 12.04 / VirtualBox "Login Incorrect" but doesn't even ask for a password

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh, login

I have a virtual box machine running on Ubuntu Server 12.04 (for almost 4 years now) and now suddenly I can't acess it via SSH anymore because the machine somehow lost it's network connectivity (IPs were set to static to specific 2 interfaces that are bridge to the main server). I had the same problem yesterday, but after restarting the machine one of the network cards worked, from where I could acess it and reconfigure the "new" (new mac) virtual network adapter, so everything was working fine until today (I woke up and the machine was shutdown, probably a power outage).

The thing is, for some time now I have ignored the main problem, which is the topic of this question (*text mode, any TTY*), **when you go visual mode** *(I usually start the machines using the command line)* **and start the machine from VirtualBox and try to login locally, just about a second or two after typing the username the machie returns "Login Incorrect"**, it doesn't even gives me a chance to type the password. SSH works fine even though this problem exists.

Here's a quick demo of the problem happening: https://gfycat.com/YellowishOffensiveHackee

I have tried booting from a CD and removing the root/otheruser password from shadow, but the error persisted. I'm really curious why this happens, as I have no idea on what to do besides creating a new virtual machine and moving the stuff to that one (probably a good time to say goodbye to VirtualBox, too).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very odd. If you type `root` does it still fail?